# Compiling ASM with C and having result "NaN" or "-NaN". Square Root Function

Tags: c, assembly, square-root

I had errors with compiling earlier but after working on them, got no errors/warnings. Altho the result given is NaN.

Here is code:

C:

```
iclude <stdio.h>

extern float wynik1 (int a, int b, int c);
extern float wynik2 (int a, int b, int c);

int a = 2;
int b = 2;
int c = 2;

int main ()
{

float licz1 = 0;
float licz2 = 0;

licz1 = wynik1(a, b, c);
licz2 = wynik2(a, b, c);

printf("Roots : %f oraz %f \n", licz1, licz2);

return 0;
}
```

ASM1:

```
SYSEXIT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
STDIN = 0

.align 32
.data

a: .int 2
b: .int 2
c: .int 2
buf: .float 0
x1: .float 0

cztery: .float 4
dwa: .float 2

.text
.global wynik1

wynik1:

xor %eax, %eax
xor %ebx, %ebx
xor %ecx, %ecx

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
movl 16(%ebp), %eax
pushl %eax
pushl %ebx
pushl %ecx

movl %eax, a
movl %ebx, b
movl %ecx, c

finit 
fld a
fld c

deltaa1:
fmulp
fld cztery
fmulp
fld b
fld b
fmulp
fsubp

pierwiastek1:
fsqrt
fld b
fchs
fsubp
fstp buf
fld a
fld dwa
fmulp
fld buf
fdivp
fstp x1

movl x1, %eax

movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

ASM2:

```
SYSEXIT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
STDOUT = 1
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0
STDIN = 0

.align 32
.data

a: .int 2
b: .int 2
c: .int 2
buf: .float 0
x2: .float 0
cztery: .float 4
dwa: .float 2

.text
.global wynik2

wynik2:

xor %eax, %eax
xor %ebx, %ebx
xor %ecx, %ecx

pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movl 8(%ebp), %ecx
movl 12(%ebp), %ebx
movl 16(%ebp), %eax
pushl %eax
pushl %ebx
pushl %ecx

movl %eax, a
movl %ebx, b
movl %ecx, c

finit 
fld a
fld c

deltaa2:
fmulp
fld cztery
fmulp
fld b
fld b
fmulp
fsubp

pierwiastek2:
fsqrt
fld b
fchs
faddp
fstp buf
fld a
fld dwa
fmulp
fld buf
fdivp
fstp x2


movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

So yeah. The return in C code is "- nan and - -nan". I have no idea hod to overcome this after some hours of checking registers and changing code.

Code in C = intput and output.

ASM1 is couting root 1 and ASM2 is counting root 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: In your debugger, have you verified that your registers are receiving the correct values from the stack?  Also, when single stepping, when does your value go to NAN?  That usually means a negative square root attempt or possible divide by 0.  Both should be shown when single stepping in your assembler file in a debugger.

Comment: it's full code, only this 3 codes are compiled together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `fld a`, while you should be doing `fild a` to load an integer to the floating point stack (converting it to float); as those variables are integers, not floats.

E.g. integer 2 loaded as float is a denormal with magnitude of about 2^-140. This multiplied with another small number makes zero.

Then the last `fdivp` divides 0.0 by 0.0, which is by definition a NaN.

Comment: Should I change every fld to fild?

Comment: @sadasfsdafasfgasgasd obviously not. Look at the *reason* why it was wrong. Some of the `fld`s really *do* load things that are meant to be floats, so they should stay `fld`'s.

Comment: I did other way, changed every int to float without changing fld to fild, and still got -nan.

Comment: Do you think int should stay int and changed those to fild? Will this help?

Comment: I believe it's a good time to start using a debugger. If you lack one, I'd suggest you to move the exit block of your routine until you find the place where the return value differs from the expected value. (Also sqrt(x), when x is negative is a good candidate for a floating point operation to produce a NaN.) (And while you are moving the exit block, make sure the stack is balanced and all the callee-saved registers are restored.)

Comment: I am using gbd, but i have no idea how can i check what is under "a", "b" "buf" etc. The only command I know about is "info register" where I can check what is under eax, ebx etc.

Comment: That's a good start. Doesn't the info register also output the FP stack? `break main` or `break myasmroutine`, `run` and start to step (`S`) each line of code. You can also `print a`; provided that the variable is in the _scope_ of the function.

Comment: thanks for the print! ok so the problem is reaaaaly early. When you check ASM1: finit; fild a; fild c; deltaa1:; fmulp. so i added variable test1: .int 0 (check with float, same result), print a was 2, print c was 2, print test1 before mulp was 0, and after mulp... 1082130432. What is the problem here? I chanhed flds to fild there.

Comment: And after the next mulp i added another variable test2: .float 0, and after mulping with 4 it gives -4194304. While it shoule be 4ac, so 4*2*2= 16...

Comment: My last hint for today: add a dummy variable `a_d` after `a`, `b_d` after `b` etc. and check if those variables "accidentally" change. I don't want to debug all your code, but given the symptoms, it may be that 64-bit results are written to 32-bit variables.

Comment: Ok.. but where can I add them? Sorry, I am dummy at asm still (hard). fild a; fild a_d; fild b; fild b_d will change mulp anyway so it's not the way I am thinking after reading your advice. Sorry for taking so much time.